# Propel / mssql : last insert ID

Tags: sql-server, symfony, propel

We use Symfony2, Propel and triggers with a mssql server. The problem is the following:
* from a form, we insert a new object in the DB
* then a trigger is used to log the insertion into a table
* then from the propel object we get the inserted ID => it is false.

After further analysis, propel gets the last inserted ID in the DB using the PHP function PDO::lastInsertId which returns the ID of the row inserted into the log table.

I think that Propel should use SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() instead, this will return the object ID as the trigger is ran into another context.

The question is: how to tell to propel to use this function? In the Propel bundle, there is a MssqlPropelPDO class whose implementation is:

```
public function lastInsertId($seqname = null)
{
    $result = self::query('SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()');

    return (int) $result->fetchColumn();
}
```

But this class isn't used from my code, instead this is DebugPDO (I saw into into the BasePeer class).

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better using the `OUTPUT` clause then fetching it back with PDO:

***eg.***

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO product (product_name) OUTPUT INSERTED.product_id VALUES (?)";

$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);

$sth->execute(array('widgets'));

$temp = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

You can read up on `OUTPUT` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx).